# WebVTT File For Live Stream

Tags: video, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, closed-captions, webvtt

I am trying to implement the closed captioning for live stream.

The video is generated from the source and converted to m3u8 + ts file through the encoder and put in the server. video is in 3 bit rates for adaptive streaming.

The speech to text convertor is giving the XML files for the speech along with the timestamp in UTC (I could change to any time zone) which binds with the video stream for which it is generated.

Is it possible to use the XML data in WebVTT File. In My understanding WebVTT consists of captions with the time(in hh:mm:sss.mmm format) when it will come in video. like

```html
WEBVTT
X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:900000,LOCAL:00:00:10.000

00:00:30.006 --> 00:00:30.706
Instant Folgers!

00:00:30.900 --> 00:00:31.900
Instant Folgers?

00:00:32.646 --> 00:00:33.800
Tastes good as fresh-perked.

00:00:34.446 --> 00:00:36.646
Good as fresh-perked? I'll try it.

00:00:39.446 --> 00:00:41.746
Jean, this coffee is delicious, do you know that?

00:00:41.846 --> 00:00:43.722
Mm mm

00:00:43.822 --> 00:00:45.822
It's not the same kind we've been using, is it?

00:00:45.922 --> 00:00:47.922
Mm mm

00:00:48.022 --> 00:00:49.022
Don't just shake your head.

00:00:49.122 --> 00:00:50.909
Explain why the coffee's so good

00:00:51.009 --> 00:00:53.700
Good taste.

00:00:55.409 --> 00:00:57.370
Tastes good as fresh-perked.

00:00:57.734 --> 00:01:00.134
Instant Folgers.
```

But in Livestream do we need to pass the date information along with it(hh:mm:sss.mmm) as only time will not serve the purpose as the time may be repeated for another day, led to confusion.

And How the video time is linked with the WebVTT time information in live streaming, as VOD videos have the constant time duration.

Please share any info If you have already implemented the closed caption for live stream using any technologies

Answer (score 3):

Apples developer site has all this information, and it easy to search and navigate.

They even have videos:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/512/